# Login and Registration authentication and authorization

Tags: android-studio

I have created menu bar and has two option items. If user clicks on one menu option item and log's in then he should not login again with same credentials if he clicks on other option item from same menu bar.

If user clicks on one menu option item and register's then he should not register again with same credentials if he clicks on other option item from same menu bar.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing the authenticated users in Firebase...

Make a new child **USERS** in your database.
Whenever a user log's in or registers, store the `UID` generated by Firebase in a child **USERS** with the value **Option 1** OR **Option 2**.

Your `Database` must look something like this:

```
USERS: {

UIDofPerson1(Key) : "Option 1" (Value)

UIDofPerson2(Key) : "Option 1" (Value)

UIDofPerson3(Key) : "Option 2" (Value)

}
```

Whenever a user tries to `login/register`, check the database if he has already `logged in/ registered` through some other option.

If `YES`: Display a Toast informing the user about this.
If `NO`: Let the user `Login/Register` and then save his `UID` in the database with the steps mentioned beforehand.

If you're still not sure how to proceed, just leave a comment.

Comment: I'm not using firebase. just created a simple login and registration pages

Comment: So, where are you storing the data of the authenticated users?

Comment: I need code for login and registration pages. I need it through sqlitedatabase

Comment: So use whatever I mentioned in my Answer in SQLite. Create Database Users with two columns: Key and Value. Under Key, store Username and under Value, store option number. I hope this is clear. :)

Comment: @NomulaBhavanishankar StackOverflow is for helping you. I told you the logic; now you have to code it yourself. I can't type the whole code for you.